# ffmpeg framemd5 format explanation

Tags: ffmpeg

Does a frame consist of audio and video or just video? I am trying to verify if this can be used for confirming both audio and video data were successfully sent or if I need to handle the audio separately.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [framemd5 muxer documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#framemd5):

> This muxer computes and prints the MD5 hash for each audio and video
>   packet. By default audio frames are converted to signed 16-bit raw
>   audio and video frames to raw video before computing the hash.
>
> The output of the muxer consists of a line for each audio and video
>   packet of the form:
>
> ```
> stream_index, packet_dts, packet_pts, packet_duration, packet_size, MD5
> ```
>
> MD5 is a hexadecimal number representing the computed MD5 hash for the
>   packet.

If you want to omit a particular stream or stream type use the `-map` option. This example will only process the video stream while ignoring audio:

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0:v:0 -f framemd5 -
```